# Javascript -- get only the variable part of a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

given:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("<~~include(.*?)~~>", "g");
```

What's the easist way in javascript to assign a variable to whatever's matched by .*?

I can do this, but it's a little ugly:

```
myString.match(regexp).replace("<~~include", "").replace("~~>", "");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript should return an array object on a regex match, where the zero index of the array is the whole string that was matched, and the following indexes are the capture groups. In your case, something like:

```js
var myVar = regexp.exec(myString)[1];
```

Should assign the value of the `(.*?)` capture group to `myVar`.

Comment: Won't this throw an error if there is no match? It returns null if there's no match so attempting to access the array index of a null object would throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

(Quotes from [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions))

> Including parentheses in a regular expression pattern causes the corresponding submatch to be remembered. For example, `/a(b)c/` matches the characters `'abc'` and remembers `'b'`.

Since `.*?` is the first (and only) remembered match, use `$1` in your replacement string:

```
var foo = myString.replace(regexp, '$1');
```

---

**Edit:** As per your comment, you can also (perhaps with clearer intention) do this:

```
var foo = regexp.exec(myString)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks bears. Thing is, I don't actually want to replace the whole thing, I just want to find out what the value of .*? is.

Comment: [Nick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/21399/nick) just commented (and then deleted his comment) that the first version will also work. He's correct, but I guess the intention of the `replace` version is less clear than the intention of the `exec` version. In either case, you have to assign the value returned by `replace`/`exec` to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead for part of this regular expression. See here:

[Regular expression for extracting a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392738/regular-expression-for-extracting-a-number/3398423#3398423)

and/or here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Lookaround is not the answer. How is that supposed to help?

Comment: [quote] Thanks bears. Thing is, I don't actually want to replace the whole thing, I just want to find out what the value of .*? is. – morgancodes 15 mins ago

Comment: So they could write a regex that [EDIT] matches <~~include(.*?)~~> and excludes the information they do not want.